# UIVisualEffectView as an overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that presents another `ViewController` like that:

> ```
> let blurryVC = BlurryViewController(names: ["name1, "name2", "name3"])
> let navigationC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: blurryVC)
> self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
> self.present(navigationC, animated: true, completion: nil)
> ```

on `BlurryViewController` I have a `UIVisualEffectView`, when I present this `VC` the blur works for around 1 second and then it become black. I think something happening the the view of the `VC` behind.

How can I prevent it from being black when I present it?

Thank you!